# NodeJS : Parsing csv and returning the list through a promise

Tags: node.js, csv

I am trying to parse a csv inside a node server.

I decided to try the csv module, installed using 'npm install csv'

When I execute the code below, the logs display the right value for rows. But I can't manage to export this result through a promise that I can share across my environnement.

```
var parse = require('csv-parse')
var csvPromise = fs.readFile('path/to/file.csv', function 
(err, fileData) {
  return parse(fileData, {}, function(err, rows) {
    console.log('rows', rows, err)
    return rows ;
  })
})
```

I would like to be able to call the following code in severall places.

```
csvPromise.then(function (res) {return res ;})
```

I have tried severall ways but cannot find a solution. How can I manage that ?

Comment: You could also try using https://github.com/Keyang/node-csvtojson, whiich has built-in Promise support.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
var parse = require('csv-parse');
const csvPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  fs.readFile('path/to/file.csv', (err, fileData) => {
    parse(fileData, {}, function(err, rows) {
      console.log('rows', rows, err)
      resolve(rows) ;
    });
  });
})
```

hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but csvPromise.then(function (res) {return res ;})
returns a Parser object for res... How can I extract an array ?

Comment: I just updated the answer. I'm not familiar with csv-parse. if your earlier code returns a result for rows, then it should resolve rows.

Comment: What if `readFile` or `parse` throws an error? Will it automatically reject?

Comment: `reject(err)`. It will not automatically reject. It'll get stuck till it reaches a timeout. You have to manually reject @NobleUplift

Comment: This helped me a lot with fastCSV which doesn't return a promise. Thank you.